# Providing voltage to USB port and battery terminals from same voltage regulator. Safe to do?

Tags: voltage-regulator, battery-charging

I’m trying to use my old smartphone as an IP camera. I hooked up a voltage regulator providing 4.4V straight to the battery terminals and it works perfectly. However to have the phone boot automatically after a power outage I need to provide voltage to the phone's USB port as well. I

I have this setup running right now but I'm not sure if it will damage anything in the long term.

My questions is:

Is it safe to hook the USB cable straight from the voltage regulator? Isn't the voltage regulator essentially ‘charging’ the ‘battery’ which in this case, is the voltage regulator itself?

Comment: @DAS: 
There is no battery in the setup described. Just a powersupply connected to the battery terminals of the phone.

Comment: To properly answer this question would depend on knowing the internal design of the phone, especially its PMIC and surrounding circuitry and software.  People can make likely guesses, but really this is a question about the *usage* of an *undocumented product*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, please, limit your battery voltage to 4.2. Batteries operate at 3V-4.2V (lower boundary can vary, 2.8-3.3), so anything from 3.5 to 4.2 will be 100% safe. I fix the phones from time to time, so I connect the power supply directly to the battery pins all the time :)

Excessive battery voltage, even if not much, can be harmful in the long run. One day some 3 months away from now it won't boot. Or maybe everything will be OK. In any case, it's an unnecessary risk you can easily remove.

Second of all, in order for the phone to boot, it only needs to "feel" the usb voltage just for a moment, and the internal electronics will be like HEY BRO TIME TO WAKE UP. Assuming you have already changed your voltage to 4V (which I strongly recommend), try to apply 4V to the charging port for a second and see if it starts to boot. If so, you can do the same trick as well - you can implement some short 4V pulse on the usb power line.

But KEEPING usb voltage at 4V is a BAD idea. The circuit is intended to step 5V input down to charging voltage (which varies within battery voltages, up to 4.2V). Too small difference between voltage input and output can cause all sorts of trouble. You only care about HEY WAKE UP signal.

All of this is based on assumption that 4V on USB power line will be enough for the phone to start booting. In any case I strongly advise AGAINST charging and powering battery terminals from the power supplies: battery terminal not only gives energy to the phone, but also received it when charging, and constant presence of USB will simply try to "charge" your battery terminal power supply, which is very likely not designed to sink current. CORRECTION: it won't sink current because usb and "battery" voltage is the same, but it's still not designed to have battery and charger voltage on the same level

So you need to create a pulse on the USB line. either 5v or if you're lucky 4V will be enough. Now it depends on how much into electronics you are. Making some small circuit with RC timer and a comparator can make it easy to make 1-2s pulse on USB and then go low, for instance. Mechanical switch is always an option. A microcontroller can open and close mosfet on USB power line too. Handful of options.

By the way, since you're inside the phone, you can actually wire yourself up to the power button. All you need is to pull the power button dataline down for 3 seconds and your phone will start to boot. You can easily start your phone with tweezers if you know what and where exactly to short to the ground for a moment. Nothing stops you from using it too, in fact, it would be a pretty elegant solution in my opinion, and it doesn't care about voltages too!

Comment: Unless the phone has a step up converter (which it doesn't), how would the power supply end up having to sink current that came from... the same power supply?   Actually there could be an argument for keeping the voltage at 4.2 or even a few millivolts higher, so that (fake) battery is considered fully charged.

Comment: @ChrisStratton yeah right. In any case it's not designed for such operation, so no way to say if it's healthy. It clearly wasn't designed to operate like that. But yes, you're right, there will be no sinking

Comment: Only reason I provided 4.4V is because 4.4-ish volts is where the phone starts charging properly. Any lower than that, charging goes on and off and causes the app (Alfred Cam) to nag me about charging my phone every 5 minutes. But yes the phone does 'feel' the USB voltage at 4V. So I guess maybe I should lower everything to 4V. However though Im not sure if I want to spend time doing the RC timer with pulsing. On another note my Huawei Li-ion battery does shows 2 voltage values. 3.7V with no description and Limited charge voltage: 4.2V. Any idea what that means? HB5N1H if you're interested.

Comment: it's the same battery type with same voltages. All phone batteries are nominal 3.7, with fully charged 4.2 and discharged ~3.2, battery voltage is not constant, it's average. You can make a tiny mosfet + rc on the gate circuit that will close soon after voltage applied

Comment: Just wire yourself to the power pin and short it to ground to turn the phone on. Easy solution really.

Comment: Alright I'll kinda google what you're saying there as I'm a newbie. I appreciate the help.

Comment: What phone are you talking about? It's very easy on the iphones

Comment: Huawei Ascend G 330

Comment: No info about that one, sorry, just get an arduino and one logic level mosfet to open and close usb power

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind can you please attach a diagram of your setup. A hand drawn diagram will be enough. It's little bit difficult to understand some points

As I understood, attaching a regulator directly to a battery terminal might not be a good idea(In long term as you mentioned). Batteries need controlled charging. Smartphones have charging controllers built in. It's better to let the phone to take care of the battery charging. Usually when a USB cable attached it charges the battery as well.

Comment: There is no battery in the setup described.  Just a powersupply connected to the battery terminals of the phone.